# How do you pass a chunk of an array to an inout function? Type-erasure?

Tags: swift, type-erasure, inout

I have a function

```
func doThing(inout array: [Int]) { //thing }
```

I have the array

```
var stuff = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want `doThing` to operate on just the first three elements.

```
doThing(&stuff[0..<3])
```

doesn't work since

```
var partOfStuff: ArraySlice<Int> = stuff[0..<3]
```

and `doThing` does not accept `ArraySlice`s. The best thing I can think of would be to embed `stuff` into `AnyCollectionType` or some other type-erased struct and change the arguments of `doStuff` to be the type-erased type. But that hardly seems worth the effort and very inelegant, I think just not using `inout` would be better.

Anybody have a better way?

Comment: You could cast the slice to an Array... You could have `doThing` take an `_ArrayType`... Really, without knowing what `doThing` _does_, it's hard to be helpful. Why does it need to take an `inout [Int]`?

Answer (score 0):

`ArraySlice` is copy-on-write so when you use it as `inout`, you are modifying a copy of the original array. It's better to pass the indices that you want to modify:

```
// Double the elements at the indicated indices
func doThing(inout array: [Int], onIndices indices: [Int]) {
    for i in indices {
        array[i] *= 2
    }
}

var stuff = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
doThing(&stuff, onIndices: Array(0..<3))
```